# Install mplayer on Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, yum, repository, dependencies

I've been trying for several days to install mplayer on Centos 7 without success, I've install many repos but nothing works, I've always the following error:

```
-> Resolve Dependencies completed
Error: Package: 4: mplayer-1.2-93_snap20140413.el7.x86_64 (atrpms)
           Requires: libaudio.so.2 () (64bit)
Error: Package: 4: mplayer-1.2-93_snap20140413.el7.x86_64 (atrpms)
           Requires: libvga.so.1 () (64bit)
Error: Package: 4: mplayer-1.2-93_snap20140413.el7.x86_64 (atrpms)
           Requires: libartsc.so.0 () (64bit)
Error: Package: mpg123-1.18.1-1.el7.x86_64 (atrpms)
           Requires: libaudio.so.2 () (64bit)
Error: Package: 4:mplayer-1.2-93_snap20140413.el7.x86_64 (atrpms)
           Requires: libnemesi.so.1 () (64bit)
Error: Package: mpg123-1.18.1-1.el7.x86_64 (atrpms)
           Requires: libartsc.so.0 () (64bit)
You can try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You can try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I use the following repos :

```
yum repolist enabled

atrpms/7/x86_64                       Fedora Core 7 - x86_64 - ATrpms                                       827
base/7/x86_64                         CentOS-7 - Base                                                     8 465
epel/x86_64                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                      7 419
extras/7/x86_64                       CentOS-7 - Extras                                                     104
rpmforge                              RHEL 7 - RPMforge.net - dag                                           245
rpmforge-extras                       RHEL 7 - RPMforge.net - extras                                         10
updates/7/x86_64                      CentOS-7 - Updates 
repolist: 18 794
```

Any idea ?

Comment: It may be multiple repos offering `mplayer` and treading on each other's feet.  Have you tried using `--disablerepo=atrpms`, to get purely rpmforge-based components?

Comment: I don't think the atrpms repo is right ...I found the RPM here: http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/atrpms/el7/x86_64/stable/index.html I would expect the entry to be `atrpms/el7/x86_64` and not `atrpms/7/x86_64`.

Comment: mplayer is not on any other repo i use, only on atrpms. I've reinstall atrpms with your link, but nothing has changed the entry is atrpms/7/x86_64. I think the problem is that the libraries were not updated for Centos 7 but I would find a way to make it work on Centos 7 beacause downgrade to Centos 6 would be problematic for me.

Comment: You might be stuck compiling it from source in that case.

Comment: Unless you're actually looking for mencoder, you're probably better off using a different video player, such as vlc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your help, I find a solution, I've download on [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net) and install the missing dependencies one by one but for Fedora 20 64 bits (dependencies for Fedora 19 64 bits is uncomplete), it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Mplayer for EL7/CentOS7 is in [RPM Fusion](http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/7/x86_64/repoview/unspecified.group.html).

So just do

```
curl -O https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm
```

to get the Free repo RPM, plus

```
curl -O https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-7.noarch.rpm
```

if you also want the non-free codecs, then do

```
sudo yum localinstall *.rpm
```

and then

```
sudo yum install mplayer
```

Comment: FWIW, this technique shown by @Tantallion worked fine on Sci Linux 7.6 (Nitrogen) with the exact commands shown. I liked this technique because it showed precise commands.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is missing dependencies.  Maybe CentOS 7 is still new and does not have all packages built for it yet.  It looks like you may be able to use fedora 19 packages instead.  That is, download the packages you need from a fedora19 yum repo and then install them.

It looks like you could follow this tutorial:
http://hasis053341.blogspot.com/2014/07/installing-mplayer-on-centos-7.html

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way for me to install `mplayer` on RHEL 7.3 was to manually put the

- *fedora* and
- *rpmfusion for Fedora*

repositories in my repository directory `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.

I just copied them from another machine, which had Fedora 21 installed and changed the `$releasever` variable to 20.

### Create the repository files

The following commands will create the repository files for rpmfusion and fedora in your repository directory (copy and paste them to your RHEL 7 or CentOS 7 terminal):

```
echo '[fedora]
name=Fedora 20 - $basearch
failovermethod=priority
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/20/Everything/$basearch/os/
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-20&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearch' | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo

echo '[updates]
name=Fedora 20 - $basearch - Updates
failovermethod=priority
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/20/$basearch/
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f20&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearch' | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo

echo '[rpmfusion-free]
name=RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Free
#baseurl=http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/20/Everything/$basearch/os/
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-20&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-20' | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free.repo

echo '[rpmfusion-free-updates]
name=RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Free - Updates
#baseurl=http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/updates/20/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-updates-released-20&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-20' | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates.repo

echo '[rpmfusion-nonfree]
name=RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Nonfree
#baseurl=http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/releases/20/Everything/$basearch/os/
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=nonfree-fedora-20&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-nonfree-fedora-20' | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-nonfree.repo

echo '[rpmfusion-nonfree-updates]
name=RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Nonfree - Updates
#baseurl=http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/updates/20/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=nonfree-fedora-updates-released-20&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-nonfree-fedora-20' | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-nonfree-updates.repo
```

### Install mplayer

First, to avoid any conflicts with old stuff in the database, do this:

```
sudo yum clean all
```

Now just install mplayer:

```
sudo yum install --nogpgcheck mplayer
```

I used the option `--nogpgcheck` to disable the gpgcheck. Otherwise you have to import the gpg-keys (I didn’t do so).

### Disable or remove the repo files

Then remove the repo files (or set `enabled` to 0).

Disable them:

```
sudo sed -i 's%enabled=1%enabled=0%' /etc/yum.repos.d/{fedora*,rpmfusion-*}
```

Or remove them:

```
sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/{fedora*,rpmfusion-*}
```

### PS:

You can now also install `ffmpeg` etc.

Comment: Bug was inside, now it works (single quotes needed).